# git branch output without indent whitespace? (besides regex manipulation)

Tags: git, bash, git-branch

Is there a `git branch` option that will print all branches without the two spaces in front of the branch name? I thought `--porcelain` would be supported but apparently not for branch listing.

What I'm trying to do: I want to script deletion of merged branches without using low level regex manipulation like one would with `awk`, or in my case perl (so that my script is elegant and readable):

```
git branch | perl -pe 's{^\s*}{}g' | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

(Off topic, but for those who tend to hoard and hate deleting, this is a nice quick way to purge what you really don't need and keep a clean repo)

Comment: One could (ab)use `while read -r line` as `read` would trim leading and trailing whitespaces when `IFS` is unchanged.

Comment: Good to know. The main reason I would want to avoid that is for the unrelated reason that I hate loops and insist on pipes.

Comment: PetSerAl - I get `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: `git for-each-ref refs/heads --format "%(refname)"`

Comment: Thanks. To get rid of the prefix, add `basename`. Please post as an answer so that I can give you credit ;) `git for-each-ref refs/heads --format "%(refname)" | xargs -n 1 basename`

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat: don't use `basename`; it tries to treat these as file names.  Consider what it does to the branch named `feature/top` and the other unrelated branch `bug/top`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git for-each-ref` to get some string for each matched reference in your repository:

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format "%(refname:short)"
```

or

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format "%(refname:strip=2)"
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `git branch` directly. It probably uses `for-each-ref` internally.

To list the branches, use `git branch --format "%(refname:short)"`. This does not output the `*`. Sample output:

```
develop
master
bug-123-fix-issue
task-345-do-stuff
```

To output the asterisk, use `git branch --format "%(HEAD)%(refname:short)"`. Unfortunately, this creates a space in the beginning of all the other branches. Sample output:

```
*develop
 master
 bug-123-fix-issue
 task-345-do-stuff
```

However, you can play with the command anyway you want, so you can reverse it to have the asterisk at the end. It still contains the space, but at the end.

`git branch --format "%(refname:short)%(HEAD)"`

Sample output:

```
develop*
master
bug-123-fix-issue
task-345-do-stuff
```